# Integrating a 2D function with a line of singularities

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, montecarlo, integral

How can I numerically integrate Exp[-Abs[x1]-Abs[x2]]/Abs[x1-x2] for x1 and x2 from -Infinity to Infinity?

What strategy would be adapted, Monte-Carlo? The Vegas algorithm (I tried implementations in Python and Mathematica) might work, but I cannot find a package which enables me to exclude a set of points, which Mathematica's NIntegrate does (here: Exclusions->x1 == x2). The latter however gives different answers depending on the strategy (without error messages and with integral errors only going up to 1.1, using https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75426/obtaining-an-nintegrate-error-estimate). I also go to tangent space using x->Tan[alpha] to compress the integration limits to +-pi/2.

Thank you.

[Density Plot of function along x1 and x2 (in tangent space)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTck2.png)

Comment: Hi Bill, Thank you. I see yes, it seems like it isn't integrable. I had been wondering about this but got confused as the integral I am actually interested in is a multidimensional version of this, which I think looks like it is converging in Python using Vegas, which somehow doesn't work in Mathematica. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Yes a coordinate transform which could put the line of singularities along one edge might make a Duffy or IMT coordinate transformation feasible. Due to limited time I was happy with the Python Vegas package which gave the expected physical results for higher dimensional integrals! It is incredibly fast compared to Feynart's Vegas in Mathematica (because of vectorisation and c) which means that far more integrand evaluations are possible. Due to all of the weight being concentrated near the line of singularities this could be why it is able to find convergence. Thanks again!